# catkin can't find qt_build after sudo upgrade

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ros, catkin

I was working on my project and I accidentally did sudo apt-get upgrade.
Now I have some issues that I don't understand.

When I do catkin_make in my workspace, it says that cannot find the qt_build package and that I need to install it in CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

```
    CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "qt_build" with any
  of the following names:

    qt_buildConfig.cmake
    qt_build-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "qt_build" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "qt_build_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "qt_build" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  motion_manager/CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)

---Could not find the required component 'qt_build'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "qt_build" with any
  of the following names:

    qt_buildConfig.cmake
    qt_build-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "qt_build" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "qt_build_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "qt_build" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  motion_manager/CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)
```

However, the package qt_build is already in that directory.

```
joao@joao-X580VD:~/ros_ws$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/opt/ros/kinetic
joao@joao-X580VD:~/ros_ws$ cd /opt/ros/kinetic
joao@joao-X580VD:/opt/ros/kinetic$ locate qt_build
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig/qt_build.pc
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/qt_build
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/qt_build/cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/qt_build/package.xml
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/qt_build/cmake/qt-ros.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/qt_build/cmake/qt_buildConfig-version.cmake
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/qt_build/cmake/qt_buildConfig.cmake
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_build_extra.prf
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_build_paths.prf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_build_paths.prf
```

Before the upgrade everything was working fine, but now I get this error.

Does anyone know how to solve such problem? Thank you

Comment: Did you try any of the steps suggested in the error message? It tells you how to fix the problem...

Comment: @squareskittles: According to the `echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` output, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is correctly set to the installation prefix, under which `qt_buildConfig.cmake` file could be found by CMake.